# Spring: How to redirect non-dispatcher requests to dispatcher?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have standard servlet-mapping for Dispatcher Servlet - `/app/*`. I have controller that handle `/notify` requests. I need to expose this controller as servlet on `http://[SERVER]/notify`. How to simple redirect all requests from `http://[SERVER]/notify` to `http://[SERVER]/app/notify` (but **without** other tools, like [urlrewrite](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)) ? I know i can write simple servlet instead of, and set servlet-mapping in web.xml, but want to have controller, not servlet ;)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PaymentNotificationController {

    @RequestMapping("/notify")
    void notify() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put another Dispatcher Servlet in

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Notification Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/notify/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and configure it with the same XML file as your main dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't discount urlrewrite - it only takes nanoseconds to execute, and years have gone into making it as fast as possible.

If you do throw up another Spring MVC servlet, you'll wind up with a second application context, which may not be desirable.  DispatcherServlet is a front controller, of which there is supposed to be one - so yes - you can put as many as you want in, but they're almost like little mini-apps inside your WAR.